# Setting up SSL on raspberry pi

Tags: apache, ssl, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi with apache on it, and I would like to set up SSL on it.

Issues and what I have tried:

When I try to activate the SSL module and run the command: `sudo a2enmod ssl` and `sudo a2enmod default-ssl` I get `command not found`.

My second issue is that I cannot restart the apache webserver, I would run the command `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` and as a result I get  `apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details`.

What am I doing wrong?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default-ssl.conf file in [wherever-it-is]/mods-available/default-ssl.conf

sudo nano it into existence if not,

restarting the server, have you tried "sudo service apache2 restart" or replace "restart" with "reload"?

How do you normally access services on a Pi?

Comment: Yes I have created a default-ssl.conf, I use SSH on my terminal to access the pi, but occasionally I use a remote desktop connection. When I use the command sudo service apache2 restart or the command sudo service apache2 reload, I get following message "Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."

Comment: In the case of default-ssl, when you wrote a .conf did you also write a .load?